# Splitting request url with regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex, http

i want split request url with regex

like this

**request url**

```
foo/bar/index.php?a=value1&b=value2
```

**expected result**

```
1. foo
2. bar
3. index.php
4. a=value1
5. b=value2
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @smerny ([^\/]+)+\?(\S*) and ([^\/]+)+

Comment: It's good for the question to contain everything someone needs to know in order to answer it.  Would you please click "edit" and add what you've tried to the question itself?

Answer (score 3):

```
input = "foo/bar/index.php?a=value1&b=value2"
print input.split(/[\/\?&]/)
```

Answer (score 1):

The URI spec has the answer in an appendix: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html#rfc.section.B